# Can you provide a query for this question?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a query to show me name of the sailors that reserved boats more than two times after 2011-02-04.

Here is how I defined my tables:

```
sailors  (sID, sName, age, rating)
Boats    (bID, bName, color)
reserves (sID, bID, date)
```

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: You want a query? Hey, make some effort and we will assist. But we will not do the work instead of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `sailors` with `reserves`, filter out rows before 2011-02-04, group by sailor and take only those results having a count over two.

Translate this to SQL, and you are done.